# How to trigger the fetch call in saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I created my first saga , somehow it does not get triggered:

```
function* getData() {
  console.log("getData");
  const json = yield fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(
    response => response.json()
  );
  yield put({ type: "RECEIVED_DATA", json: json.data });
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  console.log("rootSaga call");
  yield takeEvery("GET_DATA", getData);
}
```

How can I trigger the saga to call the fetch?
[Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/0xl047l54w)

Comment: have you tried saga effects "call", instead of fetch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the ***working as expected*** project: https://codesandbox.io/s/8l8l59wwp9

I've just fixed it. The details explanation will be available soon.

Firstly, for some reason, I don't know why `console.log()` method does not work in your project, you might use `alert()` method instead.

Secondly, your `getDate()` generator function should be like this:

```
function* getData() {
  console.log("getData");
  const json = yield call(() =>
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(myJson => myJson)
  );
  yield put({ type: "RECEIVED_DATA", json: json });
}
```

Thirdly, in your reducer, we should get the value of `json` property instead of `data` property of the action object.

```
...
case "RECEIVED_DATA":
  return action.json;
...
```

Finally, I've made some changes in your codes in order to display the results:

```
// index.js

function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Users data={store.getState()} getData={() => action("GET_DATA")} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

// and

// Users.js

const Users = ({ data, getData }) => (
  <div>
    hi from users
    <button onClick={() => getData()}>Get data</button>
    <ul>{data.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)}</ul>
  </div>
);
```